# Mapstruct cannot find impl

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

I am using mapstruct to transform a DTO into an object and vice versus and I am getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.rppjs.customer.online.portal.dtos.mapper.UserMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1506)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:819)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:725)
```

I can see that `UserMapper.impl` is being generated but still the above exception. My code is on github on this branch 42_RenameCodeBaseToCustomerOnlinePortal. The code is pretty simple and not many lines of code. The exception is generated as part of the `RegistrationEndpointIT.java`.

Please could you take a look where I am going wrong? It is using a gradle wrapper.

Additionally, I get the following exception when running Application.java:

> Description:
>
> Parameter 0 of constructor in
>   com.rppjs.customer.online.portal.endpoints.RegistrationEndpoint
>   required a bean of type
>   'com.rppjs.customer.online.portal.dtos.mapper.UserMapper' that could
>   not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'com.rppjs.customer.online.portal.dtos.mapper.UserMapper' in your
>   configuration.

Please note, Application.java is a Spring boot application.

Comment: Can you please share the link of the entire repo? Or add the build file here

Comment: So sorry. The repo is here: https://github.com/rajivpjs/Customer-Inventory/tree/42_RenameCodeBaseToCustomerOnlinePortal

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `RegistrationEndpoint` uses the mapper as constructor argument. Since it is a component Spring wants to autowire it. But neither `UserMapper` nor `UserMapperImpl` are spring beans, therefore the exceptions.

You have two options:

1. Remove the `UserMapper` constructor argument and get your mapper with `Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class)`. Best practive would be to also public `MAPPER` instance inside your mapper (see [the example here](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#direct-field-mappings))
2. If you need autowired dependencies inside your mapper you can define your mapper as as spring bean as follows:

---

```
@Mapper(componentModel  = "spring")
@Component
public interface UserMapper() {
   //...
}
```